# Discord.py I am trying to make a bot react to images sent in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i am trying to make the bot react to images sent in a channel. To my suprise the code works

```
@commands.Cog.listener()                                                 
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == 765992140115017758:
            await message.add_reaction("<:upvote:762456415751110697>")
```

however even though this works i keep getting an error every time someone sends an image in the channel

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> line 333, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/app/extras/misc.py", line 71, in on_message await
> message.add_reaction("<:upvote:762456415751110697>") File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/message.py",
> line 996, in add_reaction await
> self._state.http.add_reaction(self.channel.id, self.id, emoji) File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py",
> line 243, in request raise NotFound(r, data) discord.errors.NotFound:
> 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

and i am frustrated as heck any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: When you manually open such a message, is its id (full URL) actually 100% identical to the one you were trying?

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: Can you use this as the reaction , try it and let me know

Comment: @Cloud i have updated it with the full error message

Comment: I think you are getting this error because message argument is a string or image can be generated by link or a image can be a file. So whenever bot gets a file or a link it not take it as string and you get this error.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal there was nothing wrong with my code just something wrong on discord side it auto fixed it.